Have Activity and Service observe the same flow
I have an Activity and a Service who both use the Room database data.
I have the following code for observing changes to the data:
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

repository.read().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .collect { entity: List<T> ->
                     _data.update { entity }
                 }
        }

Where _data is defined:
private val _data = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<T>())

and read() is simply:
fun read(): Flow<List<T>> {
    return dao.read()
}

The problem I am having is that changes to the data via the service is not identified in the Activity and vice-versa.
How do I solve this?
Am I missing something?

You should use MutableSharedFlow because as the name suggest you can have multiple consumers of a flow

"I have the following code for observing changes to the data" -- that code refers to viewModelScope. Are you doing something to give your Service access to some ViewModel? If not, how is the Service observing this data? "changes to the data" -- do you mean changes to the database contents? "How do I solve this?" -- are you using a singleton repository? Does that repository return distinct Flow objects from read() for both consumers, or are the consumers sharing a Flow?

@tyczj How do I share that between the Service and the Activity?

@CommonsWare We used ViewModel simple to give us and easier scope for launching. Nothing much beyond that. The launch is that the database activity does not run on the main thread.

@theblitz you should have your repository as a singleton and then get that instance in both the activity and service

@tyczj they are Singletons (Objects). Going to try to use MutableSharedFlow.

@tyczj further investigation shows that the service and the activity are in different processes. Not sure it is even possible to easily pass data between them. The thing is that changing the data in the activity is actually quite rare.

If your Service and Activity are in different OS processes, you can use other mechanisms to share data: Broadcast Intent, database, etc. Do these components NEED to be in separate OS processes?
